# How to update a Django query variable using Ajax Query?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I have a search form in Django. When the user click in the submit button, the page reload and gets the new elements in a query. I'm trying to do this in an Ajax Query, but when I get the elements in the success option, I don't know how to change (assign) the new data to the variable.

JS

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'url', 
        type: "POST",
        data: "name=" + selected,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError){
            alert("xhr status: " + xhr.statusText);
        },
    });
```

view

```
 def search(request, template_name="search/search.html"):

    if request.method == 'POST':

       search_terms = request.POST.get('name')

       t_places = Place.objects.filter(category__in=search_terms)
       places =  TranslatedPlace.objects.filter(place__in=t_places)

      return HttpResponse(places)
```

HTML

```
 {% for item in places %}
     <li class="search_item">
        <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
        <div>{{ item.owner }}</div>
        <div>{{item.place.category }}</div>
        <div>{{item.locality}}, {{item.county}}</div>
     </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

When I receive the new data in the 'data' variable in Ajax how I can change it in the Django 'places' variable?

Comment: can you post the `html` that the python spits out

Comment: The ajax succes options gets the elements in the query, I don't return any HTML code in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the following code inside the ajax success handler

```
$("li.search_item").find("div").each(function(i,j){
$(j).html("one"+(i+1));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/AueSp/1/

Comment: I think that the Jquery html function makes my code hard because I have the autopaginate (pagination module) installed in Django so when the user change the page I have to change the data another time. Isn't there another form to do that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen that I need to do like this, so I'm going to use Dajax.